# What does "VBoxManage modifyvm --usbcardreader on"

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

In the documentation of Virtualbox I noticed a setting I do not understand.
Can someone explain to me understandably what "VBoxManage modifyvm --usbcardreader on" do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=79221) thread, it appears that this command allows the VM to access USB card readers, such as SD and smart card readers.

> The following setting defines access to a USB Card Reader by the guest environment. USB card readers are typically used for accessing data on memory cards such as CompactFlash (CF), Secure Digital (SD) or MultiMediaCard (MMC).
>
> `VBoxManage modifyvm <uuid|vmname> --usbcardreader on|off`
>
> `Enables/disables the USB card reader interface.`

Comment: You might consider adding further quoted reference from the content of the link you provided in case the link ever go bad, the content will still be on the answer.

Comment: @Facebook Thanks for the suggestion - I fixed it.